# Docker swarm worker node cannot serve the nginx service it is hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to set up a docker swarm on two test AWS EC2 instances, but I'm running into a problem when I try to access the service from the IP address of the worker node.

On the master server, I ran `docker swarm init`. Then I took the output token and ran `docker swarm join --token <token> <Master Private IP>:2377`

Then I did a simple `docker service create -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx` on the master, followed by a `docker service scale nginx=2`. Now, checking with `docker service ps nginx` gives the following:

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
idux5dftj9oj        nginx.1             nginx:latest        ip-172-31-13-2      Running             Running 12 minutes ago                       
2nwfw3fncybj        nginx.2             nginx:latest        ip-172-31-14-130    Running             Running 38 seconds ago
```

I've opened the inbound ports on the security groups [according to this guide](https://www.bretfisher.com/docker-swarm-firewall-ports/), specifically:

- TCP port 2377
- TCP and UDP port 7946
- UDP port 4789

The master and worker servers have the same security group, so I just set the source to itself.

When I run `curl http://localhost` on the master, it gives me this, which proves it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
<!-- Omitting this for brevity -->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<!-- Omitting this for brevity -->
</body>
```

But on the worker, I just get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

A `docker ps` on the worker gives me:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b37770b153db        nginx:latest                    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       80/tcp                   nginx.2.2nwfw3fncybjj7qzeierlx0xr
```

Running `docker service inspect nginx` on the master gives:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "887xm47oavn367w0o4bo1nmce",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 652
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2019-05-19T07:50:54.491113206Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-05-19T08:02:53.454804111Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "nginx",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "nginx:latest@sha256:23b4dcdf0d34d4a129755fc6f52e1c6e23bb34ea011b315d87e193033bcd1b68",
                    "Init": false,
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 2
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "PreviousSpec": {
            "Name": "nginx",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "nginx:latest@sha256:23b4dcdf0d34d4a129755fc6f52e1c6e23bb34ea011b315d87e193033bcd1b68",
                    "Init": false,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 80,
                    "PublishedPort": 80,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "6scdvoeno2tviu4zgyldmq6b4",
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.82/16"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here's the master's `docker info`

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: q4h5ahgxf1xwuyi2aotyt20iy
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: r88oqh59x74bl1kqrcg5od2qd
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
 Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
 SubnetSize: 24
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 172.31.13.2
 Manager Addresses:
  172.31.13.2:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1021-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.945GiB
Name: ip-172-31-13-2
ID: RM34:I2IM:EJ2V:W74X:ECSD:ABCC:ZB4T:B7UO:OIWW:SUQ2:ILDB:HQLQ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

And here's the worker's `docker info`

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 18.09.5
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: slya32xwjmklumhm23bt7xs6m
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 172.31.14.130
 Manager Addresses:
  172.31.13.2:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1021-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.945GiB
Name: ip-172-31-14-130
ID: X7FI:3VCW:OCVI:5XSX:HJ24:2NOD:NQYU:SEYL:JVIJ:J4DI:F5UL:NKZT
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: bizmd
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

As far as I've read, there should not be any problems after adding the worker to the swarm and creating a service. Despite that, the worker cannot access the nginx service that it is already hosting.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the idea to check which ports were actually opened in my worker server (as opposed to just which were opened on the firewall).

`netstat -tulpn` showed me:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9443                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp    19968      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 172.31.14.130:68        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

I noticed that no process was consuming 7946, which is one of the ports that needed to be opened up. So I restarted the docker service: `sudo service docker restart`

After the restart finished, I saw a process start up and consumed the port. Sure enough, I was then able to execute `curl localhost` against either node.